# AngularJS + jQuery Raty - directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've create a directive on `AngularJS` based on `jQuery Raty` plugin.

```
patclin.directive("ngRaty", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            $(elem).raty({
                hints: ['Muito insatisfeito', 'Insatisfeito', 'Indiferente', 'Satisfeito', 'Muito satisfeito'],
                score: scope[attrs.ngModel] === null || scope[attrs.ngModel] === undefined ? 0 : scope[attrs.ngModel],
                click: function(score, event) {
                    scope[attrs.ngModel] = score;
                    console.log('Current ' + attrs.ngModel + ' value: ' + scope[attrs.ngModel]);
                }
            });  
    }
}
});
```

My big problem is when I click on the stars. If I click on a star into a component `<div ng-model="model.ratedValue" ng-raty></div>`, this value is not filled properly on the scope. When I click on a star, I set the value of that property into the scope. Displaying on that `console.log(...)` line, the value is correctly setted. But, when I try to call the same value from the controller, the value is displaying `undefined` or 0.

```
patclin.controller('PesquisaPatclinController', ['$scope', 'FormularioService', 
    function($scope, FormularioService) {

    $scope.model = {
        ratedValue: 0
    };
    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.model.ratedValue);
    }
}]);
```

I don't know what can be the problem. Can you help me?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but I hope this helps. The solution you're looking for is to add a

```
scope.$apply();
```

right after you set the model:

```
$(elem).raty({
            hints: ['Muito insatisfeito', 'Insatisfeito', 'Indiferente', 'Satisfeito', 'Muito satisfeito'],
            score: scope[attrs.ngModel] === null || scope[attrs.ngModel] === undefined ? 0 : scope[attrs.ngModel],
            click: function(score, event) {
                //Set the model value
                scope[attrs.ngModel] = score;

                //Apply the changes so that the controller and any $watch on the model will be notified
                scope.$apply();

                console.log('Current ' + attrs.ngModel + ' value: ' + scope[attrs.ngModel]);
            }
        });
```

The change to the ngModel isn't triggered because you are setting the value manually [[More on $apply](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)].

I just borrowed some of your directive to create my own, and I have it working, so if you need  an example, I can throw it up on a demo somewhere.  Hopefully you found a solution by now, or have moved on in the mean time, but I thought I'd share what I found. Maybe it will be of use to you.

Comment: ps. Thanks for guiding me to a few solutions to my own problems :)